# Sqlalchemy, trouble linking multiple columns. Foreign key Error.

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

For some reason I get a foreign key error when a I try to link a certain aspect of my Actions table with my contacts table. The error I get is:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Contacts.actions
>   - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which
>   should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

**I need help understanding why the already linked table doesnt apply to the second attribute.** (see line surrounded by comments in code below)

My Declarative Code:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    # Here we define columns for the table person
    # Notice that each column is also a normal Python instance attribute.
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    first_name =  Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    last_name =  Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    email =  Column(String(40), nullable=False)
    phone =  Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    #default_duration =  Column(Integer(2))

class Actions(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'actions'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    action = Column(String(15), nullable=False)
    message =  Column(String(140), nullable=False)
    duration =  Column(Integer(2), nullable=False)



class Contacts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'contacts'
    # Here we define columns for the table address.
    # Notice that each column is also a normal Python instance attribute.
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    contact_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    time_of_last_message = Column(String(40))
    message_log = Column(String(450))
    users_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    users = relationship(Users)

     ##############################
    #### If this line is commented it out, it works
    #### But If it is present I get the error
    actions_action = Column(String, ForeignKey('actions.action'))
    ####
    ###############################

    actions_id =  Column(Integer, ForeignKey('actions.id'))
    actions = relationship(Actions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, as the error message says, you have multiple foreign keys between `Contacts` and `Actions`, namely `actions_id` and `actions_action`, so it doesn't know which one you want to use for the relationship `actions`. You can fix it by specifying (again, as the error message suggests) `foreign_keys`:

```
actions = relationship(Actions, foreign_keys=actions_id)
```

This fixes the error, but a better question would be why you would need `actions_action` in addition to `actions_id`?

Comment: Does this mean that I cannot have an additional column from the Actions table linked to the Contacts table?

Comment: @ExperimentsWithCode You can, but why do you need to? What do you intend for it to do if `actions_id` fully identifies a row in `Actions` alone? Plus `Action.action` is not unique either, so it makes no sense to have a foreign key pointing to it.

Comment: Essentially, if an action exists I need all the columns to exist too, but if one doesnt exist, its ok for none of those fields to be populated. Thats why I separated them into their own table. However, I would love the ability to sort Contacts based on the Action assigned to them. So really I want to filter Contacts based on the value of action in table Actions. I felt it would be easiest if that value was visible on the Contacts table.

Comment: @ExperimentsWithCode That's not what foreign keys are for. Your particular situation can be solved by joining the two tables when querying, or, you can denormalize the data and **copy** the action value onto the `contacts` table, but you shouldn't have a foreign key like that.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. This is my first time diving into sql type database so i'm still getting a grasp of things. Really appreciate your input.